# How to set or delete a cookie from io.use

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

In the socket.io's `Server` object, which I will call `io` for convenience, the `use` method has access to the Express' `request` object and also a `handshake` object. Are these read-only objects?

```
io.use(function(socket,next)) {
   var req = socket.request;
   //how do I delete or set a cookie here?
   next();
}
```

I want to delete a cookie. How do I go about doing it?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't, because that would require sending an HTTP _response_, which you can't from a SocketIO connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can emit events from socket.io and the client will set/clear cookies:

server:

```
const cookie = require('cookie');

let someCookie = cookie.serialize('foo', 'bar');
socket.emit('set_cookie', someCookie);
socket.emit('delete_cookie', 'foo');
```

client:

```
socket.on('set_cookie', (cookie) => {
    document.cookie = cookie;
});
socket.on('delete_cookie', (cookie) => {
    document.cookie = cookie + '=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
});
```